# How can I call destructor for only derived class?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, polymorphism

I have two class Base and Derived. When I made only a Derived object in main and write return 0, I saw that , Destructor of base class and destructor of derived class are both called.

Thus I made an error. The base class destructor work for deleting memory which has been already deleting by derived class destructor.

So , I don't want to call destructor of base class. I want only call derived class destructor because I made only derived class object.

This is my code and my error.

```
#include <new>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    Base(){
        size=4;
        arr= new int[size];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            arr[i]=0;
        }
    }
    ~Base(){
         cout<<"Base class destructor called"<<endl;
         delete[] arr;
    }
protected:
    int *arr;
    int size;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(){
        size=5;
        arr= new int[size];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            arr[i]=0;
        }
    }
    ~Derived(){
        cout<<"Derived class destructor called"<<endl;
        delete[] arr;
    }

};

int main(){
    Derived derivedObject;
    return 0;
}
```

My error is that,

```
Derived class destructor called
Base class destructor called
*** Error in `./exe': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000001f20c40 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f2d65d147e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7f2d65d1d37a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f2d65d2153c]
./exe[0x400c31]
./exe[0x400d31]
./exe[0x400afb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f2d65cbd830]
./exe[0x4009f9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1183568                            /home/burhan/Desktop/hw5-1/exe
00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 08:06 1183568                            /home/burhan/Desktop/hw5-1/exe
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 08:06 1183568                            /home/burhan/Desktop/hw5-1/exe
01f0f000-01f41000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f2d60000000-7f2d60021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2d60021000-7f2d64000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2d65994000-7f2d65a9c000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2110523                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f2d65a9c000-7f2d65c9b000 ---p 00108000 08:06 2110523                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f2d65c9b000-7f2d65c9c000 r--p 00107000 08:06 2110523                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f2d65c9c000-7f2d65c9d000 rw-p 00108000 08:06 2110523                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f2d65c9d000-7f2d65e5d000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2110528                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f2d65e5d000-7f2d6605d000 ---p 001c0000 08:06 2110528                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f2d6605d000-7f2d66061000 r--p 001c0000 08:06 2110528                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f2d66061000-7f2d66063000 rw-p 001c4000 08:06 2110528                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f2d66063000-7f2d66067000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2d66067000-7f2d6607d000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2102075                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f2d6607d000-7f2d6627c000 ---p 00016000 08:06 2102075                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f2d6627c000-7f2d6627d000 rw-p 00015000 08:06 2102075                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f2d6627d000-7f2d663ef000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1966485                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f2d663ef000-7f2d665ef000 ---p 00172000 08:06 1966485                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f2d665ef000-7f2d665f9000 r--p 00172000 08:06 1966485                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f2d665f9000-7f2d665fb000 rw-p 0017c000 08:06 1966485                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f2d665fb000-7f2d665ff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2d665ff000-7f2d66625000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2110506                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f2d667ff000-7f2d66804000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2d66821000-7f2d66824000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2d66824000-7f2d66825000 r--p 00025000 08:06 2110506                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f2d66825000-7f2d66826000 rw-p 00026000 08:06 2110506                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f2d66826000-7f2d66827000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffe7cad2000-7ffe7caf3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffe7cb04000-7ffe7cb06000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffe7cb06000-7ffe7cb08000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: You don't. The derived class should not interfere with the base class' internals. You should also be using `std::unique_ptr` and avoid writing a destructor altogether

Comment: A derived class has an instance of the base class. Let the base class destructor destroy base class things.

Comment: OK,what can I do for this error?

Comment: Stop calling `delete[] arr;` in both Base and Derived. Use a `unique_ptr` like @PasserBy said.

Comment: Also, you're leaking memory.

Comment: I can't understand what is 'unique_ptr' ? Could you write code this?

Comment: Google the word.

Comment: The real question is: Why do you allocate and delete the array `arr`in `Derived`, when `Base` is responsible for its allocation?

Answer (score 1):

> When I made only a Derived object in main and write return 0, I saw that , Deconstructor of base and derived both called

Yes, the Derived object contains a base-class subobject of type Base.

The base-class subobject is responsible for it's own initialization and destruction. So, you should delegate cleanup of the base-class object's state to the base-class destructor.

Similarly, you should delegate construction of the base-class object to the base-class constructor: this is *already* happening implicitly, so your derived-class constructor leaks memory.

Comment: But, our teacher said that, "Constructor and Deconstructor couldn't be inherit". I don't understand.So Could you write code this example .

Comment: You're not inheriting the constructor - the base-class subobject is just being created and destroyed like any other subobject. If you have a data member of type `Base` that is _also_ responsible for initializing and destroying _itself_.

Comment: Think of it this way: Base isn't very useful unless it encapsulates some state & behaviour. If you have to re-write its creation and destruction code in every derived class, why write Base in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

When you give life to an object, the object is built by the so called *costructor chain*; it means that if you want to give life to an object of type Derived, first an object of type Base must be costructed.
Every costructor has to initialize members within the class it belongs,so Base will initialize Base's members and Derived's costructor will initialize Derived's members.
 
At the same way when you need to delete a Derived object a similar chain starts, but in the opposite direction i.e. from the Derived class to the Base class.
 **The object must be demolished piece by piece**: Derived descrutor must delete only members introduced in the Derived class,not others. Instead, delete members of Base class is exclusive responsability of Base's class destructor. 
So, erase the line in Derived's destructor in which you delete the array introduced by the Base class

```
 delete[] arr;
```

and leave it only in the Base class.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Base {
protected:
  Base(std::size_t n) {
    size=n;
    arr= new int[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
      arr[i]=0;
    }
  }
public:
  Base():Base(4){}
  ~Base(){
     std::cout<<"Base class destructor called\n";
     delete[] arr;
  }
protected:
  int *arr;
  int size;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  Derived():Base(5){}
  ~Derived(){
    std::cout<<"Derived class destructor called\n";
  }
};
```

This is how you should do it.

`Base` provides a protected constructor that lets it construct-at-a-size.

`Base()` delegates to that constructor.

`Derived()` does as well.

`Base` manages the memory, `Derived` just changes the default size.

You cannot use C++ class inheritance and not have the derived class constructor call the base class constructor, nor can you not have the derived destructor not call the base class destructor.

Comment: But, our teacher said that, "Constructor and Deconstructor couldn't be inherit". @Yakk

Comment: @tarkan I cannot read your teacher's mind, and a game of telephone where a non-programmer relays what they remember the teacher saying as they understand it won't communicate anything useful.  I have no idea what the teacher means by "be inherit" in your quote, nor do I have confidence that is what the teacher actually said.  All I can do is solve your problem the right way.